# Array x and y values in textarea seprated by tab

Tags: javascript

There is an array containing many `x` and `y` values.

```js
myObj = [{
  "x": 6.2,
  "y": 21
}, {
  "x": 5.9,
  "y": 28
}, {
  "x": 5.6,
  "y": 31
}, {
  "x": 5.3,
  "y": 33
}];
```

I want to insert these `x` and `y` axis values into a `textarea` separated by tab and every new `x` and `y` value on new line.

Please look at my code and suggest me how can I do it. Your time is highly appreciated.

```html
<textarea id="txta"></textarea>
<script>
  const myObj = [{
    "x": 6.2,
    "y": 21
  }, {
    "x": 5.9,
    "y": 28
  }, {
    "x": 5.6,
    "y": 31
  }, {
    "x": 5.3,
    "y": 33
  }];
  document.getElementById("txta").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myObj);
</script>
<br>Output should be<br>
<textarea id="txta">
6.2 21
5.9 28
5.6 31
5.3 33
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you can use `map()` to coerce the array of objects to an array of strings in the format you require. From there you can `join()` the list by a line break so that each entity appears on its own line within the `textarea`.

Also note that you need to set the `value` of the `textarea`, not its `innerHTML`.

```js
const input =[{ x: 6.2, y: 21}, { x: 5.9, y: 28}, {x: 5.6, y: 31 }, { x: 5.3, y: 33 }];
let output = input.map(o => `${o.x} ${o.y}`).join('\r\n');

document.querySelector("#txta").value = output;
```

```css
textarea { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txta"></textarea>
```

Comment: can you please explain why `.join` doesn't work with forEach?

Comment: That would depend on exactly how you're using them. If you're trying to use `forEach()` after `join()` then that won't work, as join returns a string not an array.